# When should I use quote for variable in Robot test Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am using robot to write test cases for a while but I still can't figure this out in my mind, like a rule that tells me clearly when a quote is needed ?
for example, there's variable:

```
${variable}
$variable
${variable.att}
'${variable}'
"${variable}"
None
'${None}'
```

what are they when in and not in `Evaluate` keyword?

looks like `${1}` is number, `1` is string, but in `FOR` loop, there's:

`: FOR    ${variable}    IN    1    2`    Here `1` seems to be number now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Quotes

Roughly speaking, you need to add quotes whenever the variable is being treated as a python expression or statement.

When you use `Evaluate`, you are passing it python code to be executed. Python requires that strings be represented inside quotes. So, if you have a variable `${variable}` that contains the five characters `hello`, to use it with `Evaluate` you must use quotes.

For example, given the following robot statement:

```
${result}=  Evaluate  '${variable}' + " world"
```

This results in the following python code being evaluated:

```
'hello' + " world"
```

Without the quotes it would be `hello + " world"`, in which case python thinks that `hello` represents a variable.

### Numbers in curly braces (eg: ${1})

As for numbers inside curly braces, this is just a bit of extra syntax to convert a string into an actual number. This is useful when you are calling a keyword that requires an actual number rather than a string which contains digits.

The behavior of numbers in curly braces is described in the user guide here: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#number-variables
qu

### ${NONE}

${NONE} is used when you are calling a keyword -- typically python-based -- where you need to pass in the python value `None`, or compare the result of a keyword to the python value `None`. You would never put quotes around this variable. The string `None` without quotes or curly braces is seen by robot as the literal string `None`.

Comment: Thanks much, but how about the `${None}` , `'${None}'` and `None` ?